# org.apache.jackrabbit.rmi.client.ClientXASession cannot be cast to org.apache.jackrabbit.api.JackrabbitSession

Tags: jackrabbit

I am using Jackrabbit for document management system.I am trying to check the user is admin or not like below

```
Repository repository = new URLRemoteRepository("http://localhost:9090/jackrabbit-webapp-2.11.0/rmi"); 
            Session session = repository.login(new SimpleCredentials("admin", "admin".toCharArray()));
            JackrabbitSession js = (JackrabbitSession)session;
            User user = ((User) js.getUserManager().getAuthorizable(session.getUserID()));
            boolean isAdmin = user.isAdmin();
```

Here i am getting exception like below

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.jackrabbit.rmi.client.ClientXASession cannot be cast to org.apache.jackrabbit.api.JackrabbitSession
```

Can any one help me

Comment: Looks like `session` is of type `ClientXASession` not of `JackrabbitSession`

Comment: I am able to login the Jackrabbit repository. But, when i am doing usermanagement getting this exception to do UserManagement i am following the below link http://wiki.apache.org/jackrabbit/UserManagement

Comment: Did you figure out how to solve this? I'm with the same problem.